# Understanding Natural Join in SQL

Tags: mysql, join, natural-join

So I am fairly new to SQL and currently I am stuck with the concept of Natural Join.

Currently I understand that the Natural Join operator joins tables by matching all columns with the same names and discarding duplicate columns and discarding rows which do not match.

So recently I came across a question, pretty basic really, however i couldn't wrap my head around it.

So there are 2 relations R(A,B,C) and S(A,B,D)

```
    A B C           A B D
    6 8 7           5 8 7
    6 6 7           6 6 7
    7 8 6           6 8 6
```

How many rows would the following query produce?

SELECT * FROM R NATURAL JOIN S

So instantly I see two columns which 'match' they being A and B. By using Natural Join would it take into account both A and B or just A and as such, what information would be discarded.

The answer is 2 rows. Can someone please explain the method of getting 2 rows?

Thanks!

Are the 2 rows by any chance

```
    A B D
    6 6 7
    6 6 6
```

If so, I may delete this question

Comment: A natural join will join on all columns in common between the tables, which in this case is `A` and `B`.  So yes, your expected output is correct.

Comment: It would be quicker to test the hypothesis than to ask the question

Comment: Don't use natural joins - they obscure what the code is doing

Comment: Yes the output has 2 rows. No your expected output is not correct: the columns in the result are the union of the columns from the arguments. So you need to include column `C` from `R`, as well as column `D` from `S`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: the OP's result is incorrect, the result will have four columns. See AntC's comment.

Comment: Avoid natural joins like the plague. They are obscure, error prone, and difficult to debug.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use natural joins. Don't bother learning natural joins. They are an abomination.

Why? The join conditions are based on columns with the same *names*. Natural joins do not even take declared foreign key relationships into account. This can be quite dangerous. Or -- in my case -- because almost all my tables have `CreatedAt` and `CreatedBy`, they are useless anyway.

Instead, list the `join` keys. In your case (because you have `select *`), the `using` clause is most appropriate:

```
SELECT * 
FROM R JOIN
     S
     USING (A, B);
```

This also has the advantage that the keys are explicitly shown in the query, which greatly reduces the scope for errors.

Comment: _Do_ use Natural JOIN, providing your schema was designed to take advantage of it. Most schemas aren't; because Natural JOIN is not well taught/most data designers don't understand it -- as shown by the wrong answers to this q. Natural JOIN is the simplest operation in Relational Algebra, it corresponds to AND between the predicates of the two relations. SQL has a bunch of other operations named JOIN with confusing similar-but-different behaviour.

Comment: I agree Natural JOIN gets messy if you have same-named non-key/non-foreign key columns in the two tables. Suppose in this example both `R, S` have `CreatedAt, CreatedBy` as well as the columns given. Then your `SELECT *` solution produces a result with two columns named `CreatedAt`, two columns named `CreatedBy`. And SQL allows that. So that schema was not designed to take advantage of Natural JOIN. It would be nice if `USING ( )` validated that the given columns are the only ones in common.

Comment: @AntC "Natural JOIN gets messy if you have same-named non-key/non-foreign key columns in the two tables" - you mean, two column with the same name but different meanings? That's a messy situation to begin with! A better example is a referenced table of `TeamNames` and a referencing table of `Contests` with attributes `HomeTeamName` and `AwayTeamName`, requiring attributes to be renamed to be used in `NATURAL JOIN`. This is simply unavoidable and why a rename operator (which SQL has) is needed for relational completeness.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. `CreatedAt`, `CreatedBy` are metadata and shouldn't be allowed to show up in queries, no? e.g. create a `VIEW` for every table which projects away the 'metadata columns', the people writing queries against your tables might thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

At the the risk of oversimplifying, `NATURAL JOIN` performs a join on columns of the same name.

Here is a re-write (among many other possible rewrites) using more genrealized operators:

```
SELECT R.A, R.B, C, D
  FROM R, S
 WHERE R.A = S.A
       AND R.B = S.B
```

The result has four columns and two rows:

```
| A | B | C | D |
-----------------
| 6 | 6 | 7 | 7 |
| 6 | 8 | 7 | 6 |
```

Answer (score 0):

#### How Columns Are Matched

As mentioned by others the columns that match are based on the name of the column. What they didn't mention is that the NATURAL JOIN in addition to the name of the column also takes into consideration the type of the column e.g. a column of type INT will not match a column of type CHAR even if they have the same name.

#### The Cartesian Product (Cross Product)

To see what NATURAL JOIN does it is important to first understand how joins work with out the NATURAL bit. Lets look at the tables you provided when they are joined

```sql
SELECT * FROM R, S;
```

This results in this table

```
 a | b | c | a | b | d
---+---+---+---+---+---
 6 | 8 | 7 | 5 | 8 | 7
 6 | 8 | 7 | 6 | 6 | 7
 6 | 8 | 7 | 6 | 8 | 6
 6 | 6 | 7 | 5 | 8 | 7
 6 | 6 | 7 | 6 | 6 | 7
 6 | 6 | 7 | 6 | 8 | 6
 7 | 8 | 6 | 5 | 8 | 7
 7 | 8 | 6 | 6 | 6 | 7
 7 | 8 | 6 | 6 | 8 | 6
```

as you can see each pair of possible R-row S-row combinations are represented. There are 3 rows in R and 3 rows in S resulting in 3x3 = 9 total rows.

#### What NATURAL JOIN does

NATURAL JOIN sees that both tables have columns called 'a' and both have a column called 'b'. Since it can see that the columns 'a' and 'b' exist in both tables it uses them to join. The rows where both 'a' and 'b' match across the R and S tables will be added to the result. Lets look at a single set of matching rows for an example

The row in R

```
 a | b | c
---+---+---
 6 | 8 | 7
```

will match with the row in S

```
 a | b | d
---+---+---
 6 | 8 | 6
```

the resulting row will look like this.

```
 a | b | c | d
---+---+---+---
 6 | 8 | 7 | 6
```

Each set of matching rows will correspond to a matching row in the result table. Notice that the columns that match across the tables only are represented once in the resulting row.

Any Row that does not not match a row in the table it is being joined to will not be represented in the resulting table.

When I run this query

```
SELECT * FROM R NATURAL JOIN S;
```

I get this result

```
 a | b | c | d
---+---+---+---
 6 | 6 | 7 | 7
 6 | 8 | 7 | 6
```